# MOQ For TOTAL Products In The Cart

Tags: checkout, cart

I need a way to set MOQ per group based on the total amount of units in the cart. The current magento MOQ option is applied per product. I need it to kick an error if someone has added < 40 units of an product in their cart. I'd prefer an extension that lets me set this per group because there are sometimes exceptions to the rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use event `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options`

```
`class Company_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if( your-min-qty-condition-here){
            // throw an exception here
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thanks bud. If I set this will there be anyway I can override it for specific groups or set different MOQ's based on group?

Comment: Yes, you can add any logic you need. The quote object contains all items an you can iterate them to check any conditions. Pls accept the answer if helpful or clarify what would you like to do/modify

Comment: Amasty - thank you so much for your help. What I am looking for is a module that will allow me to set MOQ based on total items in the cart. The current MOQ option in Magento does MOQ but it is based on quantity for each product. I just need it to kick an error if the accumulative item count for all items in the cart is below 40. If your above code will allow that where do I add it? Sorry I'm still new to Magento . I'm moving over from OpenCart

Comment: It really should be a good start for your customization. All you need is to implement your bisness logic depending the groups.

Comment: OK, Perfect. Where/How do I implement this code? Do I have to modify a core file, template file or make a module? Again, I'm very new to the innerworkings of Magento